# Trying to read multi valued items using YAML

Tags: perl, oracle, yaml

I am building a script that will install database software. Depending on the release I will need to be able to connect to one or more databases and I will need passwords for different users. Hence when we build the patch we can specify in one file what the customer needs to include in a separate YAML file and use YAML to read the values and check whether or not we have the right information from the customer.

I want to create a multi-valued field with a nested hash using YAML. This is what I came up with. But the formatting is wrong. Can someone help me to format in a control file this as well as how to access the values from Perl code?

```
db_targets_required:
    -  target_name: PROD_NAMEA
       username1:   system
       username2:   myschema
       username3:   myschema2
       username4:   myschema3
    -  target_name: PROD_NAMEB
       username1:   system
```

I updated the format as follows and it is recognized. This should work for me.
Thanks.

Comment: I did not ask on Stack Overflow because I have never used Stack Overflow. I suppose if I post it there now it will be considered a duplicate post. ;-)

Comment: I guess I have used it. It's hard to know the best place to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the Perl structure, just use the [YAML](http://p3rl.org/YAML) module to convert it to YAML.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;

my $struct = [ 'PROD_NAMEA' => [qw[ system myschema myschema2 myschema3 ]],
               'PROD_NAMEB' => [qw[ system ]],
             ];
print Dump($struct);
```